# Why is isnormal() saying a value is normal when it isn't?

Tags: c, floating-point, mingw-w64

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>

void PrintBytes( const float value )
{
    const char* const byte = ( const char* )&value ;
    for( size_t i = 0 ; i < sizeof( value ) ; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%02hhx" , byte[i] );
    }   
}

int main(void) 
{
    float value = FLT_MIN;

    while( 1 )
    {
        printf( "%e %d " , value , isnormal( value ) );
        PrintBytes( value );
        puts( "" );

        if( !isnormal( value ) )
        {
            break;
        }

        value /= 2.0F;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
1.175494e-038 1 00008000
5.877472e-039 1 00004000
2.938736e-039 1 00002000
1.469368e-039 1 00001000
7.346840e-040 1 00000800
3.673420e-040 1 00000400
1.836710e-040 1 00000200
9.183550e-041 1 00000100
4.591775e-041 1 00800000
2.295887e-041 1 00400000
1.147944e-041 1 00200000
5.739719e-042 1 00100000
2.869859e-042 1 00080000
1.434930e-042 1 00040000
7.174648e-043 1 00020000
3.587324e-043 1 00010000
1.793662e-043 1 80000000
8.968310e-044 1 40000000
4.484155e-044 1 20000000
2.242078e-044 1 10000000
1.121039e-044 1 08000000
5.605194e-045 1 04000000
2.802597e-045 1 02000000
1.401298e-045 1 01000000
0.000000e+000 0 00000000
```

Clearly the second value `5.877472e-039` is subnormal, since its exponent becomes 0, `00004000`.

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/GOBRwh) produces a correct result:

```
1.175494e-38 1 00008000
5.877472e-39 0 00004000
```

I'm compiling my code using gcc (MinGW-w64) on Windows.

Comment: As [`isnormal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/isnormal) is defined as a *macro*, what does your macro on your implementation that seems to fail present as? It may be worth looking in to.

Comment: Just a guess:  Is the macro incorrectly converting the argument to type double?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis judging by the output, that would be my interpretation as well.

Comment: Actually passing a double to isnormal() gives: *error: conversion to 'float' from 'double' may alter its value* Not sure if related.

Comment: @this: In my GCC library `isnormal` is implemented through `#define fpclassify(__x)  ((sizeof(__x) == sizeof(float))  ? __fpclassifyf(__x) : __fpclassifyd(__x))`. Sounds like someone accidentally got the `?:` logic reversed in your version. `float` is dispatched to `double` version of the test, while `double` is sent to `float` version.

Comment: @AnT The code macro is correct, since it is in fact calling __fpclassifyf. But the function is calling inline assembly. Replacing that inline assembly with a correct version gives correct results.

Comment: @this: Yeah, it doesn't even work properly for `double`. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: This code causes undefined behaviour. `%hhx` is only for printing `unsigned char`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I don't think so because: *hh Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a
signed char or unsigned char argument*

Comment: @this `d` and `i` cover signed argument, and the others cover unsigned argument. You can see this same convention used elsewhere in the same section, e.g. for `l`

Comment: @MattMcNabb I quoted the Standard, which states that you can use hhx for signed or unsigned char. char is defined to be either signed or unsigned. You are free to ask a new question if you feel unsure about this. I don't think such comments on this question which is about something completely different are appropriate here.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I quoted the standard verbatim. The code is defined. Whether it is or not is not relevant to this question. Open a new question if you feel unsure about it, I don't.

Comment: @MattMcNabb It is not relevant, because if we assume you are correct, then the code can be trivially fixed. Additionally what you are talking about has nothing to do with the question and is therefore off-topic. The code is defined. Here is the full quote from the Standard, *hh Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a
signed char or unsigned char argument (the argument will have
been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be
converted to signed char or unsigned char before printing)* Read this and *stop* spamming this question.

Comment: The meaning of the modifiers is to modify what the specifiers do; for example `%lx` means that we take the definition of `%x` (from point 8) but change `int` to `long`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That works as expected on other platforms (here, on [ideone](http://ideone.com/3vikuK), for example) so it is probably an issue with the gcc/standard library version you are using.

The most probable cause is that the argument to `isnormal` is being converted to a double.

Comment: I wonder if the C standard allows this (it does say that floating point operations may internally be done in higher precision than the actual type)

Comment: @matt: I don't think so. The wording in the description of theclassification macros is that the expression is first narrowed to its semantic type and there is a footnote explaining why that is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in MinGW-w64 with 32-bit target.

My output:

- MinGW-w64 x86_64-4.9.2-win32-seh-rt_v3-rev1:  Correct
- MinGW-w64 i686-4.9.2-win32-dwarf-rt_v4-rev2:  Incorrect
- Cygwin i686-pc-cygwin (gcc 4.9.2): Correct

---

Looking at the MinGW-W64 headers:

```
#define isnormal(x) (fpclassify(x) == FP_NORMAL)
```

Then we have:

```
#define fpclassify(x) (sizeof (x) == sizeof (float) ? __fpclassifyf (x)   \
  : sizeof (x) == sizeof (double) ? __fpclassify (x) \
  : __fpclassifyl (x))
```

The `__fpclassifyf` function implementation is:

```
  __CRT_INLINE int __cdecl __fpclassifyf (float x) {
#ifdef __x86_64__
    __mingw_flt_type_t hlp;

    hlp.x = x;
    hlp.val &= 0x7fffffff;
    if (hlp.val == 0)
      return FP_ZERO;
    if (hlp.val < 0x800000)
      return FP_SUBNORMAL;
    if (hlp.val >= 0x7f800000)
      return (hlp.val > 0x7f800000 ? FP_NAN : FP_INFINITE);
    return FP_NORMAL;
#else
    unsigned short sw;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("fxam; fstsw %%ax;" : "=a" (sw): "t" (x));
    return sw & (FP_NAN | FP_NORMAL | FP_ZERO );
#endif
  }
```

Since the x64 version seems to work but the i686 version doesn't, I guess we should blame the above `fxam; fstsw` line.  I started a [new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737376/should-fxam-work-for-single-precision-floating-point-values/) for this question; so far it has been answered that `fxam` does test a version which was widened to 80-bit precision.

The generated assembly at `-O1` in the broken version is:

```
    call    ___main
    flds    LC1
    fstps   24(%esp)
L7:
    flds    24(%esp)
/APP
 # 484 "F:/Prog/mingw-w64/i686-4.9.2-win32-dwarf-rt_v4-rev2/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/math.h" 1
    fxam; fstsw %ax;
 # 0 "" 2
/NO_APP
    andw    $17664, %ax
    cmpw    $1024, %ax
    sete    %al
    movzbl  %al, %eax
    movl    %eax, 12(%esp)
    fstpl   4(%esp)
    movl    $LC2, (%esp)
    call    _printf
    flds    24(%esp)
    fstps   (%esp)
    call    _PrintBytes
    movl    $LC3, (%esp)
    call    _puts
    flds    24(%esp)
/APP
 # 484 "F:/Prog/mingw-w64/i686-4.9.2-win32-dwarf-rt_v4-rev2/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/math.h" 1
    fxam; fstsw %ax;
 # 0 "" 2
/NO_APP
    andw    $17664, %ax
    cmpw    $1024, %ax
    jne L6
    fmuls   LC4
    fstps   24(%esp)
    jmp L7
L6:
    fstp    %st(0)
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE41:
    .section .rdata,"dr"
    .align 4
LC1:
    .long   8388608
    .align 4
LC4:
    .long   1056964608
```

Comment: I'm not an x87 expert, but it seems to me unlikely that FXAM will do the right thing. By the time that instruction is executed, the fact that the value was single precision has been lost.

Comment: Cygwin works correctly, but it links to external `__fpclassifyf` and I'm not sure where the source code is for that